# php - Unique High Traffic Visitor Counter

Tags: php, mysql, unique, counter, visitor-statistic

I would like to add an visitor counter to my website.

Max Stats:

1 Million Views per minute

6 Queries per Page loading

So I ask you,
**Is MYSQL and PHP for an unique Visitor Counter the best solution?**

Or should I use something different?

Comment: The answer partly depends on how you are using PHP and MySQL to keep track of the counter.  I am curious why there would be 6 queries per page for a single visitor counter.

Comment: The question is completely offtopic, there's no mention about the hardware being used or **how** you use MySQL and PHP (they are very powerful, but 99% of developers have no clue how to use it to achieve performance). Simplest solution is not to have the counter, that number means nothing to anyone except you, it's silly. It's also the fastest possible solution.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say Queries?

Comment: With one Query I mean if I execute one Mysql Query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1 million views per minute where you count views like a hit counter (moreover with duplicate checking)... php / mysql is not going to work very well (unless you have a big farm of servers).

If you need realtime hit couting, I would do this using a combination of nginx + redis http://redis4you.com/code.php?id=009 + javascript, not using php and mysql at all.

1 - Jquery (or javascript) can check if the user has a cookie and if nor, save a "unique random hash cookie" for each (user + page) (don't just use the ip, because multiple users behind a proxy can be using that same ip, ex: large companies with a proxy for internet, universities, public wifi, etc).

2 - After generating the hash, or if cookie exists, Jquery can decide to do an asyncronous request to a nginx server, using the hash as an identifier.

3 - Nginx can talk directly to redis via upstream (very fast)(https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module) and it can also check for cookies if needed.

4 - Redis is very fast and can auto increment the values (hits) base on a key value (ex: page id), surviving reboots (unlike memcache).

5 - You can query redis from php easily, (like memcache) to display the hit count on any page.

===

Another possible way (but not realtime) would be setup a box with nginx and enable access log.

1 - On your site, include a javascript which calls a file in that nginx server like this: `http://stats.server.com/hit.js?page=12345&userhash=some_md5_hash_here`

2 - Setup a cron job on the nginx server to parse those logs for unique views.

3 - Nginx can easily serve 20K requests per second on a E3 1230v2 machine.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip

Comment: if you're happy with my answer, please accept it :)

Comment: The real answer is that PHP and MySQL would work perfectly, and MySQL is no slower than redis if you know how to use it. For a silly feature like this, doing a simple `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set counter = counter + 1` is stupidly trivial. Given the fact of low number of ipv4 addresses, one can easily construct a counter that performs well with a high number of visitors. You can queue and bulk update / insert and what not. However, the feature itself is dumb and going through the process of obtaining such a silly metric doesn't justify the effort.

Comment: Maybe with MySQL 5.7 + HHVM or PHP 7 it could be done... but 1M views a minute is 16.6K per second. I don't think PHP for this load would be the most efficient way. You need a powerful dedicated just for this and the load will be high. Sure MySQL 5.7 can be fast, but adding php in the middle it's definitely not going to be faster than redis. Nginx with redis will keep the load much, much lower. [link]https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/08/27/looking-at-redis/[/link]